# Putting Files in Ascending order (not on time stamp basis) in Unix

Tags: ls, sort

How do I list files in Ascending manner, not on time stamp basis.

EX:-
Original listing

```
A_2001
A_2002
A_2003
A_2004
B_2001
B_2002
B_2003
B_2004
```

Desired output:-

```
A_2001
B_2001
A_2002
B_2002
A_2003
B_2003
A_2004
B_2004
```

Comment: Is this really putty related? Or are you asking about the usage of `ls` or even sorting a text file (via `sort`)?

Comment: by default `ls` doesn't sort on time stamp basis, but alphabetically. To sort by time stamp, one must use the `ls -t` (newest first).

Comment: What is wrong with plain `ls -1 ?_????`?

Comment: @Franki first all A_'s then all B_'s not sorted by year.

Comment: Please clarify what you want. Are you running the `ls` command? It sorts file names in ascending order by default.

Answer (score 9):

try

```
ls ?_???? | sort -t_ -k2,2n -k1,1
```

where

- `-t_` means _ is separator
- `-k2,2` `-k1,1` means sort by k 2 and key 1